# swift - String: Shorten the first word

Tags: swift

I have string and I want to shorten the first word and make it like this;
Is there a method for this?

`var name = "John Doe"` ---> "J. Doe"

Thanks,

Comment: Any attempt that you would like to share?

Comment: I converted the string to an array, then choose the first word. But I dont know hot to manipulate the first words letters.
'
let name = "John Doe"
let wordsArray = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
var firstword = wordsArray[1]
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple function for you:

```
var name = "John Doe"
func updateName(name: String) -> String {

    let firstName: String = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").first!.uppercaseString as String
    let secondName: String = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")[1].uppercaseString as String
    let firstLetter = firstName.startIndex
    let finalLetter = firstName[firstLetter]

    return "\(finalLetter). \(secondName)"
}

updateName(name)  // "J. doe"
```

Answer (score 3):

what about try something like this, split on the space and then grab first character of first array. This is a neat trick as a string is an array of characters.

```
var name = "First Last"
var fullNameArr = split(fullName) {$0 == " "}
var shortName = "\(fullNameArr[0][0]). \(fullNameArr[1])"
```

Comment: This is a pretty decent approach actually.

Comment: Although your solution perfectly answers the question, there is one point: What if the person has a first and a second name?

Answer (score 3):

You can use components separatedByString method.

```
extension String {
    var shortName: String {
        let components = componentsSeparatedByString(" ").map{$0.capitalizedString}
        return String(components.first![startIndex]) + ". " + components.last!
    }
}
println("John Doe".shortName)    // "J. Doe"
println("leonardo savio dabus".shortName)    // "L. Dabus"
```

or as a function:

```
func shortName(fullName: String) -> String {
    let components = fullName.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").map{$0.capitalizedString}
    return String(components.first![fullName.startIndex]) + ". " + components.last!
}

let short = shortName("John Doe")   // "J. Doe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, with my limited programming experience I combine what you all give me;

```
let name = authorname
let wordsArray = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
var firstWord = wordsArray[0]
var secondWord = wordsArray[1]
var firstChar = Array(firstWord)[0]
var shortName = "\(firstChar). \(secondWord)"
self.title = shortName
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle middle, double middle, nickname etc.

```
var name = "John Aby Doe"
var fullNameArr = split(name) {$0 == " "}
if let first = fullNameArr.first {
    var shortName = "\(first[first.startIndex])."
    for part in fullNameArr {
        if part != first {
            shortName += " \(part)"
        }
    }
    println(shortName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be the alternative approach. Thanks

```
  var name = "John Doe"
     var FirstPart : String = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")[0] as String
        var secondPart : String = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")[1] as String
        var firstLetter = FirstPart[FirstPart.startIndex]
        var shortName = "\(firstLetter). \(secondPart)"
print(shortName) // prints J. Doe
```